# It takes a long time to load the home screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, home-screen

Returning to home screen after sending an SMS or making a call takes up to 7 seconds on an average where as it used to be much faster six months back. Its a Aug 2011 model. System hangs often coming alive with Force Close application message. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do all android phones have to reload their home screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17532/do-all-android-phones-have-to-reload-their-home-screen)

Answer (score 1):

Because Sammy's software is buggy! If yours is a galaxy S i9000, then there are ICS Roms on [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=665) which I found far smoother and usable on my phone than Samsung's touchwiz Gingerbread.

If you don't want to go through the hassle of rooting, flashing a custom ROM, then I suggest that you backup your data and do a factory reset.

```
settings=>privacy=>factory data reset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a custom home launcher, which is another term for home screen, instead of TouchWiz, Samsung's default launcher.  [Go Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&hl=en) is a popular one and is very customizable.  [ADW](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher&hl=en) is another one that has good performance.  Doing a search for "launcher" in the Play Store will bring up multiple options.